# Convert JSON dates without timezone

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-2

I have a webservice that returns for example a DateTime object: DepartureDate.
I use ajax to fetch this and in my view I convert the JSON date string to a javascript date object with this function:

```
function convertToDate(jsonDate) {
    return eval("new " + jsonDate.substring(1, jsonDate.length - 1));
}
```

The problem is that `new Date()` takes the local time on the clients computer in consideration, so clients in different countries get different dates. I want to get the exact date that was returned from the webservice. 
Is there any easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: what the value of the variable "jsonDate"

Comment: could be for example "/Date(1285321800000)/"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The problem is that `new Date()` takes the local time on the clients computer in consideration

Nope. Creating a new Date using the timestamp constructor takes a UTC time stamp.

For example on my machine in UTC+1:

```
new Date(0)   // Thu Jan 01 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

OK, the default `toString` *displays* this date as 01:00:00 which *looks* wrong, but that's actually the correct time. 01:00:00 in UTC+1 is 00:00:00 in UTC, which is the moment described by timestamp `0`.

If you want to display the dates you've creating from a timestamp in UTC, use `date.toUTCString()` or fetch and format the consistuent parts of the date using `getUTCFullYear()`, `getUTCMonth()` etc.

Please, though, no `eval`.

```
new Date(parseInt(jsonDate.slice(6, -1), 10))
```

Comment: Thank you for your great answer bobince. I'm not good at dates and stuff, so I might not understand everything here, but I did what you suggested, and it's still the same result. If I change my timezone on my machine, the time changes (I want them to stay the same no matter what timezone your in, and they should follow AST timezone.)

Comment: The time *displayed* by `toString()` changes to reflect your time zone, but that does not mean the date is any different. `new Date(1285321800000).getUTCHours()` is always `9` regardless of your timezone. Stick with the `getUTC...` and `setUTC...` functions and the date will behave as you expect.