# json dates and timezones

Tags: javascript, json, datetime

I have the following code:

```
$(function () {

    var thedate = "/Date(1198908717056)/";
    var thedate2 = ProcessDate(thedate)
    alert(thedate2);

});

function ProcessDate(DateString) {

    var TheDate = eval(DateString.replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//gi, "new Date($1)"));
    return TheDate;
}
```

When it runs, it returns an alert with December 29 and the time is showing as Eastern Time. **When I change the timezone on my computer, it's still showing the date in the Eastern timezone.**

My question is this: does the string "/Date(1198908717056)/" contain the timezone information or is the timezone displayed in the alert the result of the browser determining my timezone?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSON doesn't have dates](http://json.org) **at all** (it's one of JSON's flaws). Those strings are just strings.

Some frameworks, like ASP.Net, use that syntax to indicate dates. What timezone they're in will be dictated by the framework. I believe the dates are in UTC and so you can just use the [`new Date(Number)`](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.3.2) constructor to create them (more in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781121/convert-json-dates-without-timezone)). That creates the date by directly setting its internal "milliseconds since The Epoch UTC" value, more in [section 15.9](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9) of the specification. Mind you, that only works if, in fact, whatever it is creating these pseudo-date strings is using UTC.

---

**Update**: Looking at your code, although it works, this line:

```
var TheDate = eval(DateString.replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//gi, "new Date($1)"));
```

...is an abuse of `eval`. `eval` should be avoided whenever possible. Instead, if you want to keep it as a one-liner:

```
var TheDate = new Date(Number(DateString.replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//gi, "$1")));
```

...or somewhat more readably:

```
var Match = /\/Date\((\d+)\)\//gi.exec(DateString);
var TheDate;
if (Match) {
  TheDate = new Date(Number(Match[1]));
}
```

In all of those cases, the `Date` will be initialized with the UTC time value embedded in the date string. But then when you ask JavaScript to *format* the date (for instance, via `toString`), it will use your local timezone to do that. You haven't shown how you're outputting the date, so I can't tell you why the timezone seems not to change if you change your timezone (perhaps the browser didn't pick up the change?). When I do it, if I output the date as a string, it shows it in British Summer Time (which is my current timezone) if I use `toString`, or UTC if I use `toUTCString`. [Here's a live example](http://jsbin.com/akoxim) using both your original date, and a date (today's date, as I write this) that's in daylight savings time so even in the UK you can see the difference between UTC and local time.

---

**Off-topic**: In JavaScript, the overwhelming convention is to use camelCased names starting with a lower-case letter for both local variables and function names. So, `theDate` rather than `TheDate`. Initial caps are reserved for constructor functions (like `Date`). You're free to ignore the convention, of course, but it will tend to make it difficult for others to read your code.

Comment: I ran the page in pure .html format from the file system on my desktop, outside the entire .net framework, and I still get a date. Does the line var TheDate = eval(DateString.replace(/\/Date\((\d+)\)\//gi, "new Date($1)")); use pure javascript or is there a .net dependency; that'd be strange since I wasn't running it in VS or IIS.

Comment: ok, great, thanks for your explanation; makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

The timezone is taken from your current system setting. Have a look at the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) class.

The given value is in milliseconds and does not contain a timezone. The constructor of Date() expects the milliseconds to be given in UTC. If you have values with a known timezone, you should use the `dateString` constructor version.

However, as far as I know, there is no way convert between timezones in JavaScript, except for UTC and the local system timezone.