# Changing timezone when conver to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, date, datetime

I want to take date in my module with JSON format and when I am converting my date value to json then it changes the timezone ultimately date gets change for eg

```
var myDateWithJson=(new Date(2014, 03, 11).toJSON());
 alert("Date With Json " +myDateWithJson);
 var myDateWithoutJson = new Date(2014,03,11);
 alert("Date Without Json " + myDateWithoutJson);
```

I also gone through  [covert json without timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781121/convert-json-dates-without-timezone) but, I don't think that is better approch
Please guide me for the better approch

Comment: At the heart of all Date objects is a UTC time value. The best way to pass dates around is to use either the time value or an ISO 8601 string based on UTC, which is what you get from [*Date.prototype.toJSON*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.44).

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
var myDateWithJson=(new Date(2014, 03, 11).toJSON());
```

will create a date object for 00:00:00 on the morning of 11 April 2014 (note that months are zero indexed here) in your current locale based on system settings. Calling [*toJSON*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.44) returns an ISO 8601 date and time string for the equivalent moment based on UTC.

The date object will have an internal [time value](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1) that is milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.

```
var myDateWithoutJson = new Date(2014,03,11);
```

That creates a date object for exactly the same moment in time, i.e. with exactly the same [time value](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1).

```
alert("Date Without Json " + myDateWithoutJson);
```

That calls the [*toString*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.2) method of the date object that returns a human readable string representing the date and time in the current locale based on system settings.

So the first is a UTC string, the second is a local string. Both represent the exact same instant in time, and, if converted back to Date objects, will have exactly the same internal [time value](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.1).